PyGame Python AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'rect'
Дедуля подарил мне книгу как создать 1 игру на Python. Я читал ее и работал, но на этапе создания спрайта на графическое окно я столкнулся с проблемой
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Tigran\Desktop\PY\Игра\ИГРА.py", line 47, in <module>
    player.rect.x = 0 #x
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'rect

Сам код по ссылке ниже на Pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/vywidjdT
Отрывок на который жалуется:
# Объекты

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #персонаж сам
    def _init_(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite._init_(self) # type: ignore
        self.images = []

        img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("images","hero.png")).convert()
        self.images.append(img)
        self.image = self.images[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get.rect()


# Настройка
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.init()
world = pygame.display.set_mode([worldx, worldy])
player = Player() #создать спрайт
player.rect.x = 0 #x
player.rect.y = 0 #y
player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_list.add(player)

Помогите пожалуйста.

как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

init пишется с 2-мя нижними подчеркиваниями: def __init__(self): и super().__init__()

newtonioapple, не совсем понимаю что вы делаете,  но попробуйте проверить https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect

@S.Nick, сайт pygame (по крайней мере в России) не доступен.

@wchistow понятно, я не знал, но вы все верно прокомментировали в ответе на этот вопрос.

Название файла в python лучше писать маленькими буквами и на английском языке. Например: main.py. В будущем могут возникнуть проблемы с этим

Ваш метод _init_ не вызывается, потому что Python не воспринимает его как магический. Для того чтобы метод был "магическим", у него должно быть 2 нижних подчеркивания: __init__:
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #персонаж сам
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) # type: ignore (тут тоже надо 2 подчеркивания
        self.images = []

        img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("images","hero.png")).convert()
        self.images.append(img)
        self.image = self.images[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


Здравствуйте! Спасибо, это действительно помогло избавиться от ошибки про rect, но появилась другая:   File "c:\Users\Tigran\Desktop\PY\Игра\ИГРА.py", line 39, in init
self.rect = self.image.get.rect()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'pygame.surface.Surface' object has no attribute 'get'

@newtonioapple, нужно не get.rect(), а get_rect().
